# Silverlight, MVVM, and datagrid not saving changes

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, mvvm, wcf-ria-services

I'm trying to use MVVM to display a datagrid and save the changes when the row is done being edited.  Here is the XAML for the datagrid:

```
<data:DataGrid x:Name="discountsDataGrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding Discounts, Mode=TwoWay}"  MinHeight="200" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDiscount, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="RowEditEnded">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SaveChangesCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedDiscount}"  />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                    <data:DataGrid.Columns>
                        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Discount Amount" Binding="{Binding Amount}" />
                    </data:DataGrid.Columns>
                </data:DataGrid>
```

And here is the code that saves on the ViewModel:

```
public void Save(object parameter){
        if (ctx.HasChanges){
            ((IEditableObject)SelectedDiscount).EndEdit();
            ctx.SubmitChanges(SubmitOperation, null);
            RaisePropertyChange("Discounts");
        }
    }
```

Before I had the line '((IEditableObject)SelectedDiscount).EndEdit();' I would be an exception because no end edit was being called from the datagrid.  Since I'm trying to stick to MVVM, the view model shouldn't know about the datagrid that is displaying the data.  So, I added that line, the code gets executed, and the returning result shows that there was a modified entry and no validation errors occurred.  But it never sticks to the database.  Is there any reason why this code is not completely writing the values back to the database?  The ctx variable is just a RIA Services domain service.  Before going the MVVM route, I usually just called datagrid.CommitEdit(), but I shouldn't have access to it now and was hoping that the call to IEditableObject would work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Not 100% certain since this is SL so I am not posting this as an answer but in WPF you don't need to to anything with the triggers or have any explicit method to "Save" since your model will be implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and therefore the new value via the value changing in the DataGridTextColumn will get pushed to the model. Remove your trigger behaviors and see if it does not work as expected.

Comment: If I remove the triggers, nothing happens. :(

Comment: Just noted the RIA references...there should be a service between the model or embedded in the model for pushing the data to the back end.

Comment: Isn't that what the save command is doing, or are you talking on the actual IEditableObject ?

Comment: @Josh Does your model implement INotifytProperyChanged? If so have you modified the Name and then see if it is making its way to the property on the model via breakpoint or other means; if so put your save within the model...which will push it to the database thus removing the need for the triggers/command.

Comment: My model (Discount) is just the autogenerated class from WCF RIA Services.  My ViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: This is so stupid, but it ended up being no problem.  The database was configured for two decimal places and all updates I was doing was adding a 1 at the end of '.01'.  The change never appeared because the database always dropped it.  Sorry for the mixup.

Answer (score 1):

On this way works for me, I'm using SL4 , mvvm toolkit 3 and WCF RIA Services, ds= domain service

```
private void guardarFila()
{
IsBusy = true;
ds.SubmitChanges(new Action<submitoperation>(SubmitChangesCompleted), null);
}
private void SubmitChangesCompleted(SubmitOperation args)
{
IsBusy = false;
}
```